# When printf is not used normally

Tags: c

I am questioning the output value using printf.

I ran the code below and got an unusual result.

```
int i = 1, j = 2;
printf(" %x %x %x \n", i, j);
```

```
1 2 2eea5190
```

Even the third output kept changing after multiple attempts.

Recently, while studying security, we are learning about the vulnerabilities of various functions, but it is difficult to understand the output of the printf value.

Why is that value coming out?

Comment: Undefined behavior. You ask it to take three operands but provided only two, so for the third you'll get something else that happens to be in the place (register or memory) where a third operand would usually be stored.

Comment: Was there something specific you expected to happen instead?

Comment: So this can't be accurately defined?
Should I just interpret it as a junk value left in memory?

Comment: I expected it to be the return address of the main function or something.

Comment: "_I expected it to be the return address of the main function or something._" You hit the nail on the head. The value is **something**... In this case, there was no SEG_FAULT triggered by accessing memory locations that didn't belong to the executable. In another case there may be... It is unwise to waste time _trying to_ invoke UB...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string told `printf` to expect three additional arguments (four total). It looks for those arguments in the expected places (whether that's additional registers or neighboring locations on the stack depends on implementation details, primarily the calling convention in use by your OS/compiler). You didn't *provide* the fourth/final argument, so the location for that argument remains whatever random thing happened to be left over from the last time that register or memory location was used, and, as you've observed, it's typically garbage.

By the standard, it's undefined behavior and *anything* can happen, but in practice, reading garbage from wherever the calling convention says the argument *should* have been placed is the normal behavior.

Comment: Then, why can't we derive the reason for the garbage value at that location?

Comment: @KWing: You *could*. You just need to trace (or empirically determine via breakpoints) the sequence of execution to find the last time when that particular register/stack location was written. The value can be semi-random even so though; for example, if it was last used to store a pointer, [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) on modern OSes randomizes the locations of the the executable code, the stack, the heap, and any loaded libraries, so the value would differ from run to run, even if the sequence of function calls remained purely deterministic.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm not convinced it's guaranteed that the location *was* previously written to by the process at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: At least for the case of being read off the stack, given it has a non-zero value, assuming we're not on some wildly insecure OS, it would have been written by *something*; if it wasn't, it would remain all zeroes (the state all memory requested from the OS starts in). For the register case I'm not sure (and it probably varies by architecture), though I'd expect the C runtime initialization to touch most of them, at least on moderately register-constrained architectures (e.g. x86/x86-64).

Comment: Re "*but in practice*", ...this could clobber the stack by removing an argument that's not actually there, causing the stack to become completely invalid, causing the program to crash or do anything. So yeah, very much undefined behaviour. You assumes the caller clears the stack, but it's the callee that clears it in some conventions.

Comment: @ikegami: To my knowledge, for varargs functions, the only existing conventions are all caller clears (because the callee doesn't have the information necessary to clear it at compile-time in the general case), even when the convention otherwise uses callee-based clearing. It's not impossible for the callee to do it if the calling convention implicitly passes additional information on the number of arguments actually passed to a varargs function, but I've never heard of any system using such a convention (be happy to be proven wrong there).